# How to cast dictionaries stored in the session in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, casting, keyvaluepair

Placing in session:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("_ProjectRights", ProjectRepository.GetProjectRechten(user1.UserId).ToList());
```

query:

```
var data= Db.Users.SingleOrDefault(s => s.UserPk == userId)?.ProjectUser
 .Select(se => new { Key = se.primaryKey1.ToString(), 
Items = string.Join(",", se.ProjectRight.Select(sel => sel.primaryKey2).ToList()) });

IDictionary<string, string> dictionary = data.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Items);
```

Failed cast:

```
var privilegeLevelsDict = (Dictionary<string, List<string>>)HttpContext.Current.Session["_ProjectRechten"];
```

Succesful cast:

```
var privilegeLevelsDict = (List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>>)HttpContext.Current.Session["_ProjectRechten"];
```

Why does the first cast not work? Why do I have to cast to a List of KeyValuePairs instead of a dictionary, even though I first placed a dictionary in the session variable?

Comment: If the successful cast works, then presumably your session does actually contain a list. Log `HttpContext.Current.Session["_ProjectRechten"].GetType()` to confirm. (Note that the code you've got to add something to the session uses a different key. Is that just a typo when you were creating the question?)

Comment: You could foreach the sessionlist if not empty and add the items to the dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding a list to the session, here:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(
    "_ProjectRights", 
    ProjectRepository.GetProjectRechten(user1.UserId).ToList())
```

Note the `ToList()` call. If `GetProjectRechten` is returning a dictionary and that's what you *want* to be in the session (and if it can be serialized) then you could just remove the `ToList()` call.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(
    "_ProjectRights",
    ProjectRepository.GetProjectRechten(user1.UserId))
```

If you can't serialize a dictionary but want to recreate it later, you can do that easily:

```
var storedValue = HttpContext.Current.Session["_ProjectRechten"];
var list = (List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>>) storedValue;
var dictionary = list.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Comment: of course! I was so busy working in repository function and roleprovider files that I forgot and did not see the list cast anymore -_-. Thanks